# php curl - access url via browser response: 200 access url via curl response:401?

Tags: php, curl, httpresponse

I have a url which contains all information in the url (username/password/content ect)

If i visit the url in my browser I get a successful response.

However If I visit the url through curl I get 401.

There is no authentication on the url.

What could be causing this?

**Code:**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mconnect.co.nz/v1/sendmessage?appname=app&pass=pass&msgclass=test&msgid=6&body=Some+Content&to=02712345678');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $mconnect[$index]['app_name'] . ":" . $mconnect[$index]['app_pass']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.587.0 Safari/534.12');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
if(curl_exec($ch) === false) 
  echo 'fail: '.curl_error($ch);
```

---

**Update...Strange...**

So,

I am building my url through
$mconnect[$index]['url'] . '?' . http_build_query($url);

which gives me the above url.

So,

If I have

```
$url = $mconnect[$index]['url'] . '?' . http_build_query($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

I get the 401.

But,

If I then do
`echo $mconnect[$index]['url'] . '?' . http_build_query($url);`

I get

> http://mconnect.co.nz/v1/sendmessage?appname=app&pass=pass&msgclass=test&msgid=6&body=Some+Content&to=02712345678

so if I then do

```
$url = 'http://mconnect.co.nz/v1/sendmessage?appname=app&pass=pass&msgclass=test&msgid=6&body=Some+Content&to=02712345678';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Then it works...

any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you are doing HTTP post/get using cURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not sure why The fix was to build the URL myself instead of using php 5's build_query_string

Answer (score 0):

The server is likely verifying the user-agent. You probably need to set it to whatever your browser uses.

Comment: just added code, And yeah, I thought that might be the case too, but nope.

Comment: That's a very... curious User-agent. Try getting rid of the extra browsers, they may be doing something funny to prevent this...

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you're sending might need to be sent via POST.

```
$posts = array('pass' => 'password', 'body' => 'lots of content'); // ... etc;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $posts);
```

And if this is the case you might not need to use the CURLOPT_USERPWD option.

Comment: nope not post, otherwise it would not work when It was accessed directly from the browser.

Comment: It must be relying on session/cookies.  Clear your cookies then try and access it directly.  I'd bet it doesn't work at that point.

Answer (score 0):

"There is no authentication on the url." however i see

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $mconnect[$index]['app_name'] . ":" . $mconnect[$index]['app_pass']);
```

isnt that for authentication?

Note:
You may also try sending the HTTP login details like this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://'.$mconnect[$index]['app_name'] . ":" . $mconnect[$index].'@mconnect.co.nz/v........
```

Comment: @hailwood .. are you sure the username and password that are being sent are correct? try the alternative method i suggested to send the authentication details.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the authorization header manually. With something like

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($mconnect[$index]['app_name'] . ":" . $mconnect[$index]['app_pass'])));`

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8